# Count of total rows which have duplicates

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I'm trying to get a total count of all the rows in a table which have duplicates.

Here is the query I am using right now:

```
SELECT count( `id_lead` )
FROM `lead_history`
GROUP BY `id_lead`
HAVING count( * ) > 1
```

The problem is that this isn't counting the total number of rows, it is counting the total amount of times each row contains a duplicate and returning that.

So right now, it is returning like this:

```
2
4
6
2
```

Given those results, I actually want my query to return `4`, since there are 4 rows which have duplicates. The amount of duplicates each row has does not matter to me.

How would I write this query without using subqueries?

Comment: either `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` can help you mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using something like Oracle or SQL Server, you could take advantage of analytic functions.  But MySQL does not have these, so using a subquery might the best way to get your answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `lead_history`
WHERE `id_lead` IN (SELECT `id_lead` FROM `lead_history` GROUP BY `id_lead` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Note that the subquery is not correlated, so the query optimizer should be able to make this run reasonably efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `lead_history` as b
join (SELECT `id_lead` FROM `lead_history` GROUP BY `id_lead` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) a on b.id_lead=a.id_lead
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT count( * )
FROM `lead_history`
GROUP BY `id_lead`
HAVING count( * ) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just put your query in a derived table and select the count from that. No additional `in` or `join` needed:

```
select count(*) from (
    select `id_lead`
    from `lead_history`
    group by `id_lead`
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```